# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Users/apple/Desktop/Employee+Sample+Data/Employee\\ Sample\\ Data.csv'

Tags: python, data-science

I know this question has been asked before, but I am unable to solve this problem
I also know this happens when my python file is not in the same directory has my data file.
when I do

```
     import os
     os.getcwd()
```

it gives file path as:-

```
/Users/apple/PycharmProjects/pythonProject4/venv/bin/python /Users/apple/PycharmProjects/pythonProject4/main.py
```

now when I do:-

```
      os.chdir("Users/apple/Desktop/Employee+Sample+Data/Employee\ Sample\ Data.csv")
```

i.e. I try to change the directory of my python in the same directory as my file exists it shows error:-

```
  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Users/apple/Desktop/Employee+Sample+Data/Employee\\ Sample\\ Data.csv'
```

I have been stuck with it for days. I tried everything on stackoverflow and other forums but no avail. I am using Pycharm. Please help me.

Comment: "now when I do os.chdir(...)" - I can't understand why this path is expected to be valid. Is `apple` your current username on the computer? Is there a folder named `Employee+Sample+Data` (with *matching capitalization*, and with *actual plus symbols, not spaces*) on your desktop? Is there a file named `Employee\ Sample\ Data.csv` - **with actual backslashes in it** - in that folder?

Comment: You can use all forward slashes. Your path didn't start with a `/` so it is relative to the current working directory, not the root. And those spaces `\ Sample`, for instance, likely aren't right.

Comment: My best guess is that you have copied and pasted this file path out of a terminal window, after tab-completing it. The terminal will use backslashes to escape spaces in a file name, because otherwise the space would separate words in the command. But in the Python code, the file path is in a string, so there is no need to escape spaces. Python does not treat backslash-space as an escape sequence.

Comment: @tdelaney more likely the backslashes should be omitted than the spaces. Note that OP appears to be on Mac, not Windows; no Mac user would try to use backslashes as a path separator in the first place.

Comment: Perhaps `"/Users/apple/Desktop/Employee+Sample+Data/Employee Sample Data.csv"`

Comment: And you wouldn't actually chdir to that, as its a file, not a directory.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel - yes I have pasted it from the terminal

Comment: Right, that's the problem, then. Just remove the backslashes.